# SQL Server, assign key by date range

Tags: sql-server-2014

**BILLS**:

```
billdate    billno
-------------------
2015-04-13  8090
2015-03-11  8089
2015-02-14  8088
2015-02-10  8087
```

**TRANSACTIONS**

```
transactiondate billno
-----------------------
2015-04-15      8090
2015-04-13      8090
2015-04-12      8090
2015-04-10      8090
2015-03-12      8090
2015-03-11      8089
2015-03-10      8089
2015-02-11      8088
2015-02-01      8087
```

I need to assign billno to transaction line items as described above.  Transactions outside the bill range -- i.e. those beyond 2015-04-13 that don't match up within the date range window need to go with the last available bill.  And vice-versa, transactions on the bottom end such as 2015-02-01 need to go with the last available bill.

Not quite sure how to go about this query.

Comment: Are you starting with only a transactiondate in the TRANSACTIONS table and need a query to populate the TRANSACTIONS.billno field based on the transactiondate and the information in the BILLS table?

Comment: Yes.  There are account numbers as well that you would group the bills and transactions by, but the main thing, the only thing I have to associate the transactions with a bill is the date.

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see a date RANGE... only a single date. Or is the range defined by "billdate of billno till billdate-1 of billno+1"?

Comment: The range is defined by all the transactions that occur starting at the bill date of the bill and all transactions prior to that date, but after the last bill date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a cursor or a recursive common table expression (CTE).  I'd advise saying away from cursors, so here's an example of the CTE.

There's a lot going on in this query so I'll try to break it down in pieces.

If you perform a FULL JOIN against the two tables you'll come up with something that starts to look like the answer, but there are a lot of NULL values 
for each transaction:

```
DECLARE @Bills TABLE (billdate DATE, billno INT)
DECLARE @Transactions TABLE (transactiondate DATE)

INSERT INTO @Bills (billdate, billno) VALUES ('2015-04-13',  8090)
INSERT INTO @Bills (billdate, billno) VALUES ('2015-03-11',  8089)
INSERT INTO @Bills (billdate, billno) VALUES ('2015-02-14',  8088)
INSERT INTO @Bills (billdate, billno) VALUES ('2015-02-10',  8087)

INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-04-15') 
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-04-13')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-04-12')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-04-10')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-03-12')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-03-11')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-03-10')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-02-11')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-02-01')  

SELECT
    b.billdate,
    b.billno,
    t.transactiondate,
    COALESCE(b.billdate, t.transactiondate) AS [eventdate]
FROM @Bills b
FULL JOIN @Transactions t
    ON b.billdate = t.transactiondate
ORDER BY eventdate DESC
```

[image: Full Join Results]

To arrive at the solution we need to pull the previous event's billno to the current event, if the current event's billno IS NULL.

To accomplish this we can use the recursive CTE.  Recursive CTEs don't allow joins within (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) them so I had to refactor the FULL JOIN to a UNION ALL, aliased as the "AnchorSet".  The
CTE is INNER JOINed against itself, with an offset to the rownumber/eventdate, while the billno IS NULL.

```
DECLARE @Bills TABLE (billdate DATE, billno INT)
DECLARE @Transactions TABLE (transactiondate DATE)

INSERT INTO @Bills (billdate, billno) VALUES ('2015-04-13',  8090)
INSERT INTO @Bills (billdate, billno) VALUES ('2015-03-11',  8089)
INSERT INTO @Bills (billdate, billno) VALUES ('2015-02-14',  8088)
INSERT INTO @Bills (billdate, billno) VALUES ('2015-02-10',  8087)

INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-04-15') 
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-04-13')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-04-12')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-04-10')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-03-12')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-03-11')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-03-10')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-02-11')      
INSERT INTO @Transactions (transactiondate) VALUES ('2015-02-01')      

SELECT
    b.billdate,
    b.billno,
    t.transactiondate,
    COALESCE(b.billdate, t.transactiondate) AS [eventdate]
FROM @Bills b
FULL JOIN @Transactions t
    ON b.billdate = t.transactiondate
ORDER BY eventdate DESC

;WITH AnchorSet AS 
(
    SELECT
        MIN(billdate) AS billdate,
        MIN(billno) AS billno,
        MIN(transactiondate) as transactiondate,
        eventdate
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            billdate,
            billno,
            transactiondate,
            COALESCE(billdate, transactiondate) AS [eventdate]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                billdate,
                billno,
                NULL AS [transactiondate]
            FROM @Bills b

            UNION ALL

            SELECT
                NULL AS billdate,
                NULL AS billno,
                transactiondate
            FROM @transactions t
        )innerset
    )innerset2
    GROUP BY eventdate  
)
, cte (billdate, billno, transactiondate, eventdate, rownumber, recursionlevel)
AS
(
    SELECT
        billdate,
        billno,
        transactiondate,
        eventdate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eventdate DESC) AS [rownumber],
        0 AS [recursionlevel]
    FROM 
        AnchorSet
    WHERE 
        billno IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        COALESCE(RecursiveSet.billdate, cte.billdate) AS [billdate],
        COALESCE(RecursiveSet.billno, cte.billno) AS [billno],
        COALESCE(RecursiveSet.transactiondate, cte.transactiondate) AS [transactiondate],
        COALESCE(RecursiveSet.eventdate, cte.eventdate) AS [eventdate],
        COALESCE(RecursiveSet.rownumber, cte.rownumber) AS [rownumber],
        recursionlevel + 1 AS [recursionlevel]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            billdate,
            billno,
            transactiondate,
            eventdate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eventdate DESC) AS [rownumber]
        FROM AnchorSet      
    )RecursiveSet
    INNER JOIN cte ON cte.rownumber = RecursiveSet.rownumber - 1
)

SELECT
    billno,
    transactiondate
FROM
(
    SELECT
        billno,
        transactiondate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transactiondate ORDER BY transactiondate DESC, rownumber DESC, recursionlevel DESC, billno DESC) AS [finalrownumber]
    FROM cte
)SomeSet
WHERE finalrownumber = 1
ORDER BY transactiondate DESC
```

[image: Recursive CTE Results]

This will get you what you're looking for, with the exception that the final transaction will be null since it's after the last bill.  You can create a query to get the latest billno and apply it to the remaining NULL values for the transaction's billnos.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.